# post gis command prompt problem

Tags: postgis

While I'm working in post gis sql command prompt its mode changing automatically.

I mean that the general form of command prompt as follows

template_postgis=#(we type query's here)

While working some time, when a query given its changed as

**template_postgis<#**

if any key pressed its unchanged again comes as

**template_postgis<#**

how can I change this to normal form like **template_postgis=#**?

psql (8.4.5)
WARNING: Console code page (437) differs from Windows code page (1252)
         8-bit characters might not work correctly. See psql reference
         page "Notes for Windows users" for details.
Type "help" for help.

template_postgis_20=# create table cities (id int, name text, state_name text);
CREATE TABLE
template_postgis_20=# select addgeometrycolumn ('', 'cities')
template_postgis_20-# select addgeometrycolumn ('', 'cities', 'latlon', 4326, 'M
ULTIPOINT', 2);
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select"
LINE 2: select addgeometrycolumn ('', 'cities', 'latlon', 4326, 'MUL...
        ^
template_postgis_20=# SELECT addgeometrycolumn ('', 'cities', 'latlon', 4326, 'M
ULTIPOINT', 2);

### addgeometrycolumn

public.cities.latlon SRID:4326 TYPE:MULTIPOINT DIMS:2
(1 row)

template_postgis_20(# INSERT INTO cities (id, name, state_name, latlon) VALUES (
'1', 'city', 'andhra', GeometryFromText('MULTIPOINT(78.4667 17.3667,82.2200 16.9
300,81.7833 16.9833,79.3515 13.6797,83.0000 17.0000,80.6200 16.5200)', 4326);
template_postgis_20(# INSERT INTO cities (id, name, state_name, latlon) VALUES (
'1', 'city', 'andhra', GeometryFromText('MULTIPOINT(78.4667 17.3667,82.2200 16.9
300,81.7833 16.9833,79.3515 13.6797,83.0000 17.0000,80.6200 16.5200)', 4326);
template_postgis_20(# INSERT INTO cities (id, name, state_name, latlon) VALUES (
'1', 'city', 'andhra', GeometryFromText('MULTIPOINT(78.4667 17.3667,82.2200 16.9
300,81.7833 16.9833,79.3515 13.6797,83.0000 17.0000,80.6200 16.5200)', 4326);
template_postgis_20(# INSERT INTO cities (id, name, state_name, latlon) VALUES (
'1', 'city', 'andhra', GeometryFromText('MULTIPOINT(78.4667 17.3667,82.2200 16.9
300,81.7833 16.9833,79.3515 13.6797,83.0000 17.0000,80.6200 16.5200)', 4326);

template_postgis_20(#
template_postgis_20(# INSERT INTO cities (id, name, state_name, latlon) VALUES (
'1', 'city', 'andhra', GeometryFromText('MULTIPOINT(78.4667 17.3667,82.2200 16.9
300,81.7833 16.9833,79.3515 13.6797,83.0000 17.0000,80.6200 16.5200)', 4326);
template_postgis_20(# fgfgfd
template_postgis_20(# fgfdgfd
template_postgis_20(# gfdg
template_postgis_20(# re
template_postgis_20(# tre
template_postgis_20(# tr
template_postgis_20(# gfgretrytojyhftipg ccnb ds
template_postgis_20(# fgfdgfd
template_postgis_20(# fgfdgfd
template_postgis_20(# 222
template_postgis_20(# @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
template_postgis_20(#
template_postgis_20(#
template_postgis_20(#

Comment: Probably indicates that you have an incomplete query expression - perhaps a mismatch of parentheses. Try ^C (Ctrl-C) to end the current (incomplete) query, and then fix the typo errors.